# display a value in div in html using text property dynamically

Tags: html

i have a value 
    var head=comments;

comments is a string
So can i use something like

```
var hoverText='text=comments';
<div "+hoverText+"></div>
```

To display the string in the div

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="commentDiv"></div>
```

JS:

```
var div= document.getElementById('commentDiv');
var hoverText= "some comments";
div.innerHTML= hoverText;
```